# Is it possible to determine if class throws a specific exception without invoking methods from said class?

Tags: php

Assume I have several classes like this:

```
class Child extends Parent {

    public function foo() {
        try {
             ChildEngine::bar()
        } catch (Exception\Custom $e) {
             //exception handling
        }
    }
}
```

In some of these classes, `bar()` never throws the aforementioned exception in its `ChildEngine`, and in some `bar()` might throw it. On instantiating `Child` I want to see whether `Exception\Custom` is thrown in `Child` without invoking `foo()`.

Does PHP have this kind of functionality?

Comment: You could add some PHPDoc to it, but that will only help you and your IDE to check whether there are Exceptions or not. As far as i know, it is not possible to 'foresee' if exceptions are thrown.

Comment: @TobiasF. I do have PHPDocs for it, but I was wondering whether there was a way code itself could see it, not just my IDE. But thank you.

Comment: As far as i know there is no way you could check this beforehand.

Comment: A static analyser could work this out, in most cases, but doing so at runtime is almost certainly a no (consider that the exception might be thrown by some deeply nested function call, so you've got to recurse through every possible code path). What is your aim in finding this? It may be there is a better solution to your actual problem, or some deeper misunderstanding to clear up.

Comment: @IMSoP My aim was to set a specific property to `Child` instances where the exception might be thrown. I indeed figured out a more elegant solution (perhaps not super-elegant, I went with a switch statement with `instanceof` calls) for that problem.

Comment: @IvanTalanov That sounds like something the child instances should be telling the caller, e.g. `public function mightThrowExceptions(): bool`. But even then, I don't understand why you'd need to know; the calling code should only know about the contract common to all implementations, which is "this might throw, so you need to catch", or "this won't throw, because it catches internally". Hard-coding class names is asking for trouble; will you remember to update it when something changes, or you add a new child class?

Comment: @IMSoP I was considering doing it like you mentioned, however, that had to be scrapped because of other external dependencies in the code.
The exception being thrown is a sort-of "this feature isn't available for this type of child class yet" (which is a bad way to do it, I know, but the code wasn't originally mine). The hardcode and current architecture will likely go away entirely come refactoring time.